# mem_fn to mem_fn of member

Tags: c++, bind, member-functions, member-variables

This is a follow-up question to

[mem_fn to function of member object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44625665/mem-fn-to-function-of-member-object)

This is the current code.

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>

struct Int
{
    Int(int _x = 0) : x(_x) {}
    int GetInt() const { return x; }
    int x;
};

struct IntWrapper
{
    IntWrapper(int _x = 0) : test(_x) {}
    int GetWrappedInt() const { return test.GetInt(); }
    Int test;
};

template<class ContainerT, class Mem> constexpr auto maxElem(const ContainerT& _container, Mem _Pm)
{
    auto memFn = std::mem_fn(_Pm);
    return memFn(std::max_element(_container.cbegin(), _container.cend(), [&](auto _rhs, auto _lhs) { return memFn(_rhs) < memFn(_lhs); }));
}

int main()
{
    {
        std::vector<Int> vec;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        {
            vec.push_back(i * 11 % 7); // some random values
        }
        int m = maxElem(vec, &Int::GetInt);
        int n = maxElem(vec, &Int::x);
    }

    {
        std::vector<IntWrapper> vec;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        {
            vec.push_back(i * 7 % 11); // some random values
        }
        int m = maxElem(vec, &IntWrapper::GetWrappedInt);
        //int o = maxElem(vec, ???) // what if GetWrappedInt didn't exist?
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The original question was about retrieving the `x` value of the `Int` struct through an`IntWrapper` object. I used `mem_fn` for this because it doesn't seem to distinguish between a function returning an `int` and an `int` member variable (Seen in these lines:

```
        int m = maxElem(vec, &Int::GetInt);
        int n = maxElem(vec, &Int::x);
```

The solution for `IntWrapper` objects was to add `.test`

```
auto y = std::mem_fn(&Int::GetInt);
auto b = y(wrapper.test);
```

to the call. However, in the `maxElem` function, I cannot do this.

I'm wondering if there is a way to formulate the call in such a way that the `mem_fn` goes from the `IntWrapper` object directly to the `int x` variable (Without the helper function and assuming that all members are public).

```
        //int o = maxElem(vec, ???) // what if GetWrappedInt didn't exist?
```

The original approach was `auto y = std::mem_fn(&IntWrapper::test.GetInt); // ERROR`, which of course does not compile, but shows the idea.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not use lambda ?

Comment: Lambda is doable; I just want to know if it can be done with the `mem_fn`, too.

Comment: A good rule in this context: if possible prefer a lambda over `std::function`, `std::bind`, `std::mem_fn`. Lambdas are more flexible and allow the compiler more freedom to optimize.

Comment: Against my better judgement, have a look [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d866474025975f2a)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `std::mem_fn` with something different than a pointer to member (such as a pointer to member of member). So, you must use that. In your particular case, you can achieve that with

```
std::vector<IntWrapper> vec;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    vec.push_back(i * 11 % 7); // some random values
}
auto m = maxElem(vec, &IntWrapper::GetWrappedInt);
```

However, I strongly advise you to use **lambda expressions** whenever possible. `std::mem_fn` should be considered as if deprecated, since, AFAIK, it serves no purpose that cannot be achieved at least as well by other means, i.e. a lambda.